Firebase Realtime Database security rules not working in selected node
I have a problem with realtime database security rules. I can't add rules for the exact node I'm querying without getting 'PERMISSION DENIED' error.
As I want to check the last part of the patch for user IDs, I must add rules in this place.
Unfortunately, I can't easily re-format to flatten my data structure at this point. What am I missing here?
Flutter query:
    chatStream = rtdb.rtdb
      .child('chats')
      .child('0')
      .child('002')
      .child('UID2_UID1')
      .orderByChild('ts')
      .onValue
      .listen((event) {}

Database Structure as Json:
   { "chats": {
        "0": {
          "002": {
            "UID2_UID1": {
             "1705662928936": {
                "message": "message"
              },
              "1705743447655": {
                "message": "message"
              }
 }}}}}

Rules that work:
"chats": { 
    "$0":{
        "$002":{ 
            ".read": "auth != null", 
            ".write": "auth != null",
  }
 } 
 },

Rules that don't work and return the error (and that's the issue - I need that $uid1_uid2 path part to check for IDs):
"chats": {
    "$0":{
    "$002":{
    "$uid1_uid2":{ 
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
                   
    } }  }  },

EDIT:
I found the solution, the issue was deeper in my client's code, as I was checking different nodes to test the Realtime Database online/local connection.
All implementations here should work properly. Along with an older topic: Best way to manage Chat channels in Firebase this might be a good way to store and secure chat - without any data duplication.

If your code really tries to read the single room node that it has access to, your code would work. So most likely there's a mismatch somewhere, but it's hard for us to say where that is due to all the variables you use. --- Can you: 1) simplify the data structure to only use /rooms/$roomID? 2) Include that JSON as text in the question 3) Show the updated code for that structure without any undeclared variables (so just hard-coded values and variables where we can see the initialization). 4) print the error message, and then show us the code and the complete message+stack trace?

Hi! I just added the missing example, error and json in the edit. Unfortunately, I won't be able to change the data structure easily, as there is already a good amount of data saved this way. I see it as a last-resort solution if it won't be possible to set the rules in my desired node.

There's too much going on here. That's precisely why I showed an example below of what does work based on snippets you shared. If that's not the problem you have, clean up you question to only contain the problem. Don't add even more information to it, as it just becomes harder to follow. Show: 1) the minimal JSON (as JSON text, no screenshots, no schematic representation) that you're trying to read, 2) show the rules as they apply to that JSON, 3) show the minimal code that fails. --- The best way to ensure this is to set up a minimal repro similar to what I did below (e.g. in zapp.run).

You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your Firebase Database console.

I just tried to reproduce, but everything works as expected for me.
My setup is below.
Code:
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
final db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('78358207');
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
print(uid);
final roomID = uid+"_"+"otheruid";
final roomRef = db.child(roomID);

roomRef.onValue.listen((event) {
  print("Room ${roomID} has value ${event.snapshot.value}");
});

roomRef.set(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);

Rules:
{
  "rules": {
    "78358207": { 
      "$roomID":{
        ".write": "auth != null && $roomID.contains(auth.uid)",
        ".read": "auth != null && $roomID.contains(auth.uid)",        
      } 
    },
    ...

The 78358207 in the path is your question ID, so nothing magical. Aside from that all values are in the code itself. Every time I execute this code, the write operation succeeds and the value listener prints the value.
You can execute this repro here: https://zapp.run/edit/rtdb-access-key-containing-uid-zl4e06oil4f0

I found that the issue was deeper in my app code. This is a working solution to this problem - no matter the amount of nodes. Thank you for your help, Frank! I truly appreciate all the information I was able to gather and use from this and your other answers through the years!
